# How do I run safecopy in terminal?

Tags: terminal, hard-disk, safecopy

I'm very new to terminal and Linux. I have a crashed external hard drive that is spinning but won't appear on the desktop. I ran `safecopy` from terminal and this is what it said at the end

```
Description of output:
. : Between 1 and 1024 blocks successfully read.
_ : Read of block was incomplete. (possibly end of file)
    The blocksize is now reduced to read the rest.
|/| : Seek failed, source can only be read sequentially.
> : Read failed, reducing blocksize to read partial data.
! : A low level error on read attempt of smallest allowed size
    leads to a retry attempt.
[xx](+yy){ : Current block and number of bytes continuously
             read successfully up to this point.
X : Read failed on a block with minimum blocksize and is skipped.
    Unrecoverable error, destination file is padded with zeros.
    Data is now skipped until end of the unreadable area is reached.
< : Successful read after the end of a bad area causes
    backtracking with smaller blocksizes to search for the first
    readable data.
}[xx](+yy) : current block and number of bytes of recent
             continuous unreadable data.
```

I don't know what to do next.  Is it telling me that it cannot be resurrected or is it telling me that it is waiting for me to do something?

Comment: That looks like documentation about the output format. Didn't it print anything else before/after that?

Comment: What is the exact command you gave?

Answer (score 10):

I'd like to kindly point out that Daniel's answer is incorrect. The `stage#.badblocks` files tell safecopy which blocks are bad on the source. Empty files would tell safecopy that there are no damaged blocks.

Anyway, the standard procedure is:

```
safecopy --stage1 /dev/source output.img
```

which will copy the entire source and mark the bad blocks in `stage1.badblocks`. At this point, any data that is readable will be saved (ie. the data won't be corrupted any further).

```
safecopy --stage2 /dev/source output.img
```

which will try reading the bad blocks marked in `stage1.badblocks` with no retries and then mark the exact boundaries of the bad areas in `stage2.badblocks`.

```
safecopy --stage3 /dev/source output.img
```

which will continuously retry to read the bad areas marked in `stage3.badblocks`.

Note that later stages can take an incredibly long time to complete if the previous stages were not run.

Comment: After the image is made, how do you mount/open/view it? Since the image is of the entire file system, and not just a partition, I am having trouble using it.

Comment: I use testdisk for an interactive session or foremost ofr an automated recovery of files.

Answer (score 3):

You ran `safecopy` without any options, so it printed out usage information. You need to give it options so it knows what to do, `man safecopy` will show you the manual, like [this one](http://www.linuxcertif.com/man/1/safecopy/#HOWTO_198h). One possible combination would be

```
safecopy --stage3 source dest
```

Where `source` is your broken drive, and `dest` is where to copy the rescue data to.

Answer (score -2):

It seems to require you to create the file to write to first.  So run `touch stage1.badblocks` in the folder you're going to back up to.  Then run `safecopy --stage1 /dev/source /media/otherdrive/stage1.badblocks` and it will run the first stage.  After that repeat this step with making the next file `touch stage2.badblocks`... run the same code with 2 instead of one.  Then do the same for the third stage... swap the numbers out with 3.

```
    touch stage1.badblocks
    safecopy --stage1 /dev/source /media/otherdrive/stage1.badblocks

    touch stage2.badblocks
    safecopy --stage2 /dev/source /media/otherdrive/stage2.badblocks

    touch stage3.badblocks
    safecopy --stage1 /dev/source /media/otherdrive/stage3.badblocks
```