# Detect damaged audio CD

Tags: audio-cd

I need to check if a lot of audio CDs are damaged or not and would prefer not to have to listen to them all.

Is there a good way to do this quickly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[cdparanoia](http://www.xiph.org/paranoia/) can attempt to rip the audio data to a null device, and as a side effect tell you how damaged the discs are.

```
cdparanoia -q -p -X 1- /dev/null
```

Comment: On average, with good discs, this is fairly quick. With full paranoia on a scratched disk, it will take hours.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can use [`safecopy`](http://safecopy.sourceforge.net) to do this. It also has the added bonus of being able to recover data from failed/failing discs as well.

*excerpt*

> safecopy is a data recovery tool which tries to extract as much data
>   as possible from a problematic (i.e. damaged sectors) source - like
>   floppy drives, hard disk partitions, CDs, tape devices, ..., where
>   other tools like dd would fail due to I/O errors.

How to use it was covered previously in this U&L Q&A titled: [How do I run safecopy in terminal?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38490/how-do-i-run-safecopy-in-terminal).

```
$ safecopy --stage1 /dev/source /dev/null
```

After this is complete a file should show up named `stage1.badblocks`. If it's empty then the disc is fine.

Comment: Unless safecopy explicitly supports Audio CDs (they don't look like a block device), it won't work.

Comment: The websites says it can do Audio CDs.